# How to set a td height to zero if it contains just a space

Tags: css, html-table

I have an iframe page from an external site service that includes unnecessary white space as 'top-padding' formed with table rows.

```
<tr><td> </td></tr>
```

...note the space within the  element that prevents using the CSS pseudo class

```
td:empty {display: none;}
```

I have access to CSS overrides for the page but not any scripting, so I can't use jQuery.
Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: Not possible with pure CSS afaik.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suspected that this might be the case. Inspecting the elements I see a height of 13px, which I guess is the contents of a <td> element inheriting the implicit <p> font-height. I tried adding p:empty {display: none;} to the CSS but this doesn't work - as I guess there's no real <p> tag in the mark-up for this to affect.

Comment: Unfortunately `:contains()` never made it into the spec. Would have been perfect for this.

Comment: No worries, I've been able to reduce the first set of rows by setting      `margin-top: -30px`. The extra white space within the body of the page - beneath the title - is less problematic.

Comment: On which browser(s) did you observe this problem? Those that I tested (Firefox, Chrome, IE) show a cell with just a space as empty. By default it has some height, due to the default cellpadding, but the content height is zero. Is there something else in the markup that makes it 13px high as you describe in a comment? Perhaps a no-break space character (which is not treated as whitespace)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JukkaK.Korpela The issue is cross browser and the page source is exactly as quoted - rows with `<tr><td></td></tr>` are hidden OK with `td:empty {display: none;}` but not those with spaces (I'm not sure if these are &nbsp; characters as I only have access to the rendered source when inspecting). I've also tried setting `td {padding:0px}` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Please post a complete testable HTML document and explain how the issue manifests there. It is clear that `:empty` does not match an element with nonempty content, but the title of the question is about setting height to zero, but it *is* zero, so what is the problem really? Also consider posting the URL of the page, it would probably let people deduce what the problem actually is.

Comment: I would have posted the [page](http://improvedapps.com/support) previously but it was not publicly available. Please inspect the space above the Search entry widget to see the repeated `<tr><td> </td></tr>` rows which are each adding a rendered height of 13px that I'd like to remove via CSS, if possible.